# Why does this vb.net function outputs 3 rows for each value

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Why does this vb.net function outputs 3 rows for each value.

For every row in database that is returned with this query this function gives me duplicate values in listview.

Like:

```
Row1, row2, row3, row1-copy, row2-copy, row3-copy, row1-copy1, row2-copy1, row3-copy1,

Public Sub testcheckticket()
    strSQL = "SELECT *, c.coefficient FROM tickets t INNER JOIN draws d ON (FIELD(t.b1,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0) AND (FIELD(t.b2,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0) AND (FIELD(t.b3,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0) AND (FIELD(t.b4,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0) AND (FIELD(t.b5,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0) AND (FIELD(t.b6,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)>0) INNER JOIN coefficients c ON c.number = GREATEST(FIELD(t.b1,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35), FIELD(t.b2,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35), FIELD(t.b3,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35),FIELD(t.b4,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35),FIELD(t.b5,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35), FIELD(t.b6,d.1,d.2,d.3,d.4,d.5,d.6,d.7,d.8,d.9,d.10,d.11,d.12,d.13,d.14,d.15,d.16,d.17,d.18,d.19,d.20,d.21,d.22,d.23,d.24,d.25,d.26,d.27,d.28,d.29,d.30,d.31,d.32,d.33,d.34,d.35)) WHERE draw='1' AND status = '1'"
    CONNECTION.Open()
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, CONNECTION)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    ListView1.Items.Clear()

    Do While dr.Read()
        a = (dr.Item("idtickets").ToString())
        b = (dr.Item("b1").ToString() & "," & dr.Item("b2").ToString() & "," & dr.Item("b3").ToString() & "," & dr.Item("b4").ToString() & "," & dr.Item("b5").ToString() & "," & dr.Item("b6").ToString())
        c = (dr.Item("coefficient").ToString) * (dr.Item("uplata").ToString()) & " KM"
        d = (dr.Item("uplata").ToString() & " KM")
        won = (dr.Item("coefficient").ToString) * (dr.Item("uplata").ToString())


        Dim lv As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(a)
        lv.SubItems.Add(b)
        lv.SubItems.Add(c)
        lv.SubItems.Add(d)
    Loop
    dr.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
    CONNECTION.Close()
End Sub
```

Resolved: it was because of the multiple inner joins. Simple "SELECT DISTINCT" returned expecting rows without copy rows.

Comment: Have you tried to execute that query on a MySql Workbench?

Comment: I have tried to execute it with SqlFiddle, here, take a look: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f857/2